# Round an average based on decimal remainder in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, rounding, average

I need to find the remainder of a an average taken from an array so that I can properly round up or down.  Basically, if the average of the array has a decimal that is greater than or equal to 0.5, I need to round up, otherwise I need to round down.

```
long arrayaverage;
long average;
long avremain;
long output;
average = ((array1[0]+array1[1]+array1[2]+array1[3]+array1[4])/5);
avremain=average%long(1.0);
if (avremain>=0.5)
    {
    output=((average-avremain)+1);
    }
else if (avremain<0.5)
    {
    output=(average-avremain);
    }
cout<<"The average of the array is: "<<output<<endl;
```

There is my code, but the issue I think is with the modulo operator.  Whenever I try to run my code, I get the average but it always rounds up.  Any help would be much appreciated!

(side note: in an earlier segment of the code, 5 values are collected from the user to form the array, and I know there is no issue with that since an earlier part of the code runs just fine.)

Comment: You are saving `avremain` as `long`. Try using `double` instead.

Comment: Your avremain is long variable, which is int. you can't get the decimal part. Use a float variable and try to figure out how to get the decimal part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have taken everything to long and that is why it is not storing the decimal part. The avremain variable will always give 0 and so, it always show the floor of it.

Use double instead of long;

```
double arrayaverage;
double average;
double avremain;
double output;
average = ((array1[0]+array1[1]+array1[2]+array1[3]+array1[4])/5);
avremain=average - floor(average);
if (avremain>=0.5)
    {
    output=((average-avremain)+1);
    }
else if (avremain<0.5)
    {
    output=(average-avremain);
    }
cout<<"The average of the array is: "<<output<<endl;
```

To use floor, write `#include <cmath>`

Comment: It will allow me to declare avremain as a double, but it requires me to declare (1.0) as something other than a double because apparently double and long declarations do not work with binary operators like modulo.

Comment: Yes. Modulo doesn't work on doubles. Use the way I have mentioned in my code.

Comment: It does!  I imported the math library and used the floor function and it worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: No problem! :) Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to round up or down, since you're doing all your work with integral types.

```
 long sum = array1[0]+array1[1]+array1[2]+array1[3]+array1[4];

 long remainder = sum % 5L;     // 5L for consistency working with longs

 if (2*remainder > 5L)    // this will effectively round up
   sum += 5L;

 sum -= remainder;     //   sum will be a multiple of 5 now

 average = sum/5L;
```

All I've done is do the adjustments to the `sum` before dividing by the number, rather than trying to adjust the average (in which case, rounding is toward zero, and remainder information is lost).

I have assumed that the sum and therefore the average is positive.   The adjustment for negatives is trivial, and I'll leave that as an exercise.

BTW: In your code, the expression ..... `avremain=average%long(1.0)`,   `long(1.0)` is equal to `1`.   Remainder of dividing any positive integer by `1` is always zero, so your approach achieves (literally) nothing.